# Docker for PHP - 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, windows, docker

Today I decided to move from Vagrant to Docker but I get a 403 Forbidden error when accesing localhost:8080.

My file structure:

```
learning-php // root folder
  dockerconfig
    virtualhosts.conf
  web
    index.php
  docker-compose.yml
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
web:
  image: php:7.0-apache
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
    - ./dockerconfig/virtualhosts.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/virtualhosts.conf
  links:
    - mysql
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    MYSQL_USER: dev
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
```

And this is my dockerconfig/virtualhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory /var/www/html/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And in my index.php is just a call to phpinfo.
I use Windows 10 as my OS.

Please help me find where could be the problem.

Comment: On Windows docker runs in a VM so the exposed port (8080) isn't on your localhost, it's on the docker host vm. Run `docker-machine ip` to get the ip to the VM and then open `http://docker-ip:8080` in the web browser